# Vitual Studio Design view working asp.net with CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008, view

I using an external CSS to control the display of my controls. and It looks messy when I am viewing the page in th Design View of VS2008.

So whenever i change a value in my CSS, instead of examining it in design view,  i am forced to run the web page, launch my browser just in order to view the changes I made.

Comment: That is most likely a problem with (I guess) the trident engine.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd try editing your Css using Firebug with your application running.  Saving back only the changes you're happy with to you stylesheet.  Make sense?  Wouldn't have to be in debug mode either.

Comment: Thanks for your help
but (personally) I am not FF user :D

Comment: @shankarooni: if you are a web developer, shame on you if you don't test in several browsers (at the very least IE6-7, FF 3.05+, Opera9.5+ and Chrome/Safari)

Comment: Personally, if I didn't have FF installed, and I wanted to do what you want to do, I'd install it and Firebug.  If you really don't like the idea of browsing with it, just consider it a developer's tool.